# Get Xml Files From Website

Tags: c#, .net, xml, webclient

How can i get xml files from a web site and save it on pc.
what is easy way with C# ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx) from the .NET library:

```
WebClient Client = new WebClient();
Client.DownloadFile("http://foo.bar", @"C:\filename.xml");
```

Comment: @drorhan: That means you have probably used an incorrect URL.  Are you using the internet through a proxy?  That may also make a difference.  See here for HTTP error codes: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html